# How to change the number of digits in the scientific notation in l3?

Tags: siunitx, l3fp

How can I change the number of digits in the scientific notation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\num{\fp_to_scientific:n { 3785*23 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: *How* do you want it to be changed?

Comment: In most cases less than 16 digits, for example only 2 digits

Comment: Isn't this the job of `\num` rather then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,xfp}

\begin{document}

\num[scientific-notation=true]{\fpeval{3785*23}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

More examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,xfp}

\begin{document}

\num[scientific-notation=true]{\fpeval{3785*23}}

\num[scientific-notation=true,round-mode=figures]{\fpeval{3785*23}}

\num[scientific-notation=true,round-mode=figures,round-precision=3]{\fpeval{3785*23}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes thats right.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that combines `\num` from the `siunitx` package with LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\myeval[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(#1)}}

\begin{document}
\num[scientific-notation=true]{ \myeval{3785*23} } 
\end{document}
```